# Laravel 5.1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, integrity

On registering with new email, I can successfully register the new user, but when I try to make a `validation rule` to restrict an existing email from signup, instead of giving validation error message, its giving me `Integrity constraint violation error` ,

here is my `controller`

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request){
        $v = validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:30',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:30',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'mobile' => 'required|min:10',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password'
        ]);

        if ($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors($v->errors())
                ->withInput(Input::except('password', 'confirm_password'));
        }



        else{

            // validation successful ---------------------------

            /*
            add data to database
             */
```

}

and this is my `migration`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name', 80);
            $table->string('last_name', 80);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile',80);
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(0);
            $table->string('confirmation_code')->nullable();
            $table->float('amount', 80);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

How can I fix this error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Should be `$v->messages()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
 if ($v->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($v->messages()) //Not errors
            ->withInput(Input::except('password', 'confirm_password'));
    }
```

If you read the documentation of Validators.

**First Parameter:** Is for Inputs

**Second Parameter:**  Is for Rules

**Third Parameter:** Is for custom Messages

Comment: any idea why the error message caused such error to display if you can explain :)

Comment: I've added explanation.